# mousemove not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to move a div using Jquery `.mousemove()` but its working properly only 1st time mouse enter the `div#container`. My aim is to move the `div#hello` anywhere inside `div#container` cursor moves to. Please check out my code [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/0hoyd3xc/)  and please help if I am missing something.

Comment: The problem is that `animate` is expensive and your listener invokes it a few dozen times per second as you move your mouse. If you move you mouse in from the top or bottom into the middle of the element, you'll see if works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is there any other way I can do it?

Comment: Try making the animation take less time. Something like `$(this).animate({left:e.pageX},10);` in your fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you should add a container div to your html
2. you should bind event to "container" not "hello" div
3. you can manipulate css features of "hello" div.

you find code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0hoyd3xc/14/)

```
$("#container").mousemove(function (e) {
$("#result").text(e.pageX + ',' + e.pageY);
$("#hello").css('left', e.pageX);
$("#hello").css('top', e.pageY);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="hello">Hello</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#container").mousemove(function (e) {
if((e.pageX<365)&&(e.pageY<190))
{
    $("#hello").animate({left:e.pageX},0);
    $("#hello").animate({top:e.pageY},0);
}
});
```

**CSS**

```
#hello {
    position:absolute;
}
#container {
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0n7417as/)**